# Output array elements randomly with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

How could I echo 5 elements randomly from an array of about 20?

Thanks.

Comment: [`array_rand`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Is it ok to echo the same value more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$values = array_rand($input, 5);
```

Or, as a more flexible function

```
function randomValues($input, $num = 5) {
    return array_rand($input, $num);
}

//usage
$array = range('a', 'z');

//prints 5 random characters from the alphabet
print_R(randomValues($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i++; $i < 5)
{
    echo $array[rand(0, count($array)-1);
}
```

or

```
for($i=0; $i++; $i < 5)
{
    echo array_rand($array);
}
```

or

```
array_map("echo", array_rand($array, 5));
```

Comment: There is a change here that you would pick the same element more than once, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: The point of array_map is to *create a new array* by applying a function to each item of an existing array.  If all you want to do is apply the function, use array_walk.

Answer (score 0):

$n = number of random numbers to return in the array

$min = minimum number

$max = maximum number

```
function uniqueRand($n, $min = 0, $max = null)
{
    if($max === null)
    $max = getrandmax();
   $array = range($min, $max);
   $return = array();
   $keys = array_rand($array, $n);
   foreach($keys as $key)
       $return[] = $array[$key];
   return $return;
}

$randNums = uniqueRand(5, 0, count($array)-1);
for($i=0; $i++; $i < 5)
{
    echo $array[$randNums[i]);
}
```