# php maximum values to show in a list in random order?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output array elements randomly with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118842/output-array-elements-randomly-with-php)

Lets say we have this code:

```
<? if (isset($specialoffers)) { ?>
    <? foreach ($specialoffers as $value) { ?>

      <div>product #</div>

    <?};?>
<?};?>
```

For example this list may be different everytime, it may have 1 product, and it may have 58 products. I want do display only 10 products in the list and in a random order.

How to do that?

I would like not to touch the SQL query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function which takes one or more random elements from an array.

So, you could do something along the lines of:

```
foreach (array_rand($specialoffers,10) as $key) 
do_something_interesting_with $specialoffers[$key];
```

Comment: If i do this it will show only 10 positions, however i dont see: productname, price, picture.... I even changed $key to $value... still nothing changed!

Comment: You've given no indication as to the contents of your $specialoffers array.  $specialoffers[$key] will give you the corresponding value in the array - depending on what that is (it sounds like it might be another array) you'll have to process that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$specialoffers = array_splice( shuffle($specialoffers), 0, 9 );
```

Something like this might work.

Comment: shuffle returns a boolean, so this will not work

Comment: `shuffle` randomizes the array in-place.

Comment: Looks like both functions changes the array in-place, so my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shuffle()` to randomize the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try example for getting random value from assoc arrays;

```
    function array_random_assoc( $arr, $num = 1) {
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        shuffle($keys);

        $r = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            $r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
        }
        return $r;
    }

   $specialoffers = (array_random_assoc($data_array, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Reservoir Sampling](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/getting-n-random-elements-out-of-an-iterator-randomiterator/) which is even needed if the number of elements would exhaust your memory (and are presented through an iterator):

```
$randoms = new RandomIterator($specialoffers, 10);
foreach ($randoms as $value) {
   ...
}
```

You can find the [source-code of the `RandomIterator` class as Gist](https://gist.github.com/4476432).